# GPS Data from cat /dev/ttyS0 is not correct

Tags: pi-zero-w, serial, gps

I am attempting to use a Garmin 18x LVC GPS module. I have it connected to the serial RX and TX pins on my Raspberry Pi Zero W, and port name is /dev/ttyS0 on the pi.  By using a multimeter and Linux minicom I have confirmed that the TX pin of the GPS module appears to sending some kind of data.  I plan to use gpsd features eventually but right now I want to make sure that there is even data coming through so I tried to use "cat /dev/ttyS0" but the output looks like the attached picture.[image: Output of "cat /dev/ttyS0"]  I'm not sure what this means but if anyone has any guidance I would be very grateful.

Comment: Maybe a baud rate issue.

Comment: that modules default baud rate is 4800 (changeable though) or 19200 - depending on the exact module you have - what baud rate have **you** set for the serial port?

Comment: I've also read that those modules operate at between 4 and 5.5v and thus the tx voltage is whatever the module is being powered at - I hope you're not directly connecting the tx from the module to the pi

Comment: @Bravo I thought you were right about the baud rate difference between the GPS and serial port.  When I set the rate of the serial port to 4800 using "stty -F /dev/ttyS0 4800" and then read from the port again and get the same result.  I've been having trouble figuring out how to check the baud rate of the GPS but that could still be the issue.  And yes I'm using a voltage divider for pins going into the rpi.